# How to return the grep result one at a time

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have one csv file listing the orthology genes between two species (say species A and B). I am trying to use grep to find a specific A gene's orthologues in B.

For example, I want A gene AT1G01070's orthologues in B through

```
grep "AT1G01070" table.csv | cut -d"," -f 2,3,4
```

I got three B genes below as result at once

```
"Csa17g001550.1,Csa14g002110.1,Csa03g002170.1"
```

However, I need one gene at a time to feed to the following command/program. How could I manage to do that?

Comment: Define "one gene at a time". You got three because you explicitly requested three fields: `-f 2,3,4`. If you specified `-f 2` then you would get the first of the three. Is this what you want? Or do you still want three, but in separate lines? Or how?

Comment: Are the double-quotes at the start and end of your results line actually there in the output? or did you add them?  You will probably want to remove them before piping into another program.  Also, is the "following command/program" another script?  It may be easier to modify that script to extract the genes itself.   FYI, you may find the following sites to be of interest: [bioperl](https://bioperl.org/), [biopython](https://biopython.org/), and the [bioinformatics stackexchange](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/) - they may already have an exact solution for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Kamil.   Indeed I could use -f to specify one result at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be nice to see that part of the script, at least to understand *how* you feed the information to the next step.

The following might work, if the next step can handle standard input and read one line at a time:

```
grep "AT1G01070" table.csv | cut -d"," -f 2,3,4 | tr ',' '\n' | next_step
```

or maybe something like this:

```
grep "AT1G01070" table.csv | cut -d"," -f 2,3,4 | tr ',' '\n' | while read a
do
   next_step $a
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `xargs` for feeding arguments one at a time to a command, `awk` used for separating into newlines:

```
awk -F',' '/AT1G01070/ {print $2"\n"$3"\n"$4 }' table.csv |\
xargs -L 1 commandtofollow
```

Now `commandtofollow` will take one B gene at a time as argument.